# iPhone:Issues when formatting json for server request

Tags: iphone

I need to make the json params like below.

Final output should be,

```
{"submissionTime":"\/Date(1331549630849)\/",
"statusId":"0",
"answers":[{"answer":"Yes","qid":167},{"answer":"Hello","qid":168}],

"participantId":"16369",
"token":"t_ikHOXVjlcsSb9Tfdn5RaO54JGQobHodUD5881SKevxy63jwLxe8ZPQvXYss4pR"}
```

I am trying to make this format. I got the time, statusid, participantid and token. Its fine. But, i am facing problem when making "answers" array.

I use the below code for making the answers json format like below.

```
NSArray *answerkeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"answer", @"qid",nil]; 
            NSString *qID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [questionidArray objectAtIndex:i] ]; // for loop
            NSArray *objectkeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:value, qID,nil];             
            NSString *answerjsonRequest = [pSr makeJSONObject:objectkeys :answerkeys];
answerjsonRequest = [(NSString *)answerjsonRequest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

[textvaluesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", answerjsonRequest]];
```

and the output is like below.

```
    (
    "{  \"answer\" : \"Hello\",  \"qid\" : \"220421824\"}",
    "{  \"answer\" : \"How are you\",  \"qid\" : \"115781136\"}"
)
```

But, when i am adding all in one in the final output like below,

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [pSr makeJSONObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: participantID, (NULL!=textvaluesArray)?textvaluesArray:@"0", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", statusID], subTime, [appDelegate getSessionToken], nil] :[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"participantId", @"answers", @"statusId", @"submissionTime", @"token", nil] ];

The final json result is this.
{
  "submissionTime" : "\/Date(1331566698)\/",
  "token" : "t_hvYoxifLQhxEKfyw1CAgVtgOfA3DjeB9jZ3Laitlyk9fFdLNjJ4Cmv6K8s58iN",
  "participantId" : "16371",
  "answers" : [
    "{  \"answer\" : \"Hello\",  \"qid\" : \"220421824\"}",
    "{  \"answer\" : \"Hello\",  \"qid\" : \"115781136\"}"
  ],
  "statusId" : "0"
}
```

BUT, this is NOT the one what i want. My expected JSON output is top above mentioned. I tried many ways, but couldn't achieve this. Could someone helping me on this to resolve to get the exact JSON output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well, and created a quick category to take care of the problem.

```
@interface NSString (ReplaceForJSON)
- (NSString*)replaceEscapedQuotes;
@end

@implementation NSString  (ReplaceForJSON)
- (NSString*)replaceEscapedQuotes
{
    NSString* returnVal = [self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@"\""];

    returnVal = [returnVal stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"{" withString:@"{"];

    returnVal = [returnVal stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}\"" withString:@"}"];

    return returnVal;
}
@end
```

Comment: Can you please also explain how do you call and make it corrected?

Comment: `jsonRequest = [jsonRequest replaceEscapedQuotes];`